# Return a list if 2 criteria match in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, excel-formula, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula

In an effort to organize staff training: So far I've made the pivot table, but I'd like for the pivot table to extract who needs which training, as a list in one cell. I tried using =JOIN, but I have no idea what else.

**On sheet 1:**

- Row 2: Staff (who need the training), They enter "NEED" in the row of the column for that training.
- Column D: The Names of Training
- Column E: Trainers/Staff who are providing the training

[Spreadsheet Sheet 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10qRLTx6ZwHQF-w3fXZSilF-47dC4f8j9/view?usp=sharing)

**On Pivot Table**

Columns

- A: Trainer
- B: What modules they're teaching
- C: How long the training is
- D: A cell that lists who requested the training (who entered "NEED" into Sheet 1)

I'm trying to tell it simply:

- Look for the name of THIS training over in sheet 1, AND if the value of a cell in that row is "NEED", Return the Name of person/people and list it in one cell next to this pivot table......(lollll I will not cry).

The formula would be something like:

- Pull the name of the people from Sheet1!F1:Z if (Training names) Sheet1!D:D match Pivot table B:B AND there's a "NEED" in the row of that training....then list those names in ONE CELL.
- I'm over explaining I think, but this has taken all day and my brain simply cannot any longer and my own formulas sheet is not helping, Please help if you can.

[Pivot Table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1roixR_mU3bJTgTW4jFfntboEq7OngkBq/view?usp=sharing)

I have tried: =JOIN mixed with Match, then Filter... Idk what i'm doing. And the pivot table has no option to filter "NEEDS" from the whole data set. Instead it makes me filter the "NEEDS" of a Name/Column, but if i do that, it will filter out everyone elses data. Basically, it forces me to make a custom formula, which is great because I can learn, but... I really hope all of this made sense :(. Any help would be heavenly.

Comment: Can you share a copy of spreadsheet please?

Comment: Ys thank you for your help! Here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBEgN0LI8lJpmO13rlmVnHhw8sHO9XaGcgBij6S34To/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my sample sheet, try this to bring back only those who NEED training:

```
=arrayformula({"Trainer","Module","Durantion/Mins","Who NEEDS training";query(split(flatten(if(Sheet1!D5:D<>"",Sheet1!E5:E&char(9999)&Sheet1!D5:D&char(9999)&Sheet1!C5:C&char(9999)&if(Sheet1!F5:J="NEED",Sheet1!F2:J2,),)),char(9999)),"where Col4 is not null",0)})
```

[image]

My solution is shown in cell `L1` of Sheet1, but you can place it on a different sheet, updating the reference to `Sheet1!` as required.

It assumes that "Duration", "Module", "Trainer" data starts in row 5 and staff are in columns F to J. Adjust as required.

To bring back staff who NEED training and every permutation of "Duration", "Module", "Trainer" without an assigned staff, you can use:

```
=arrayformula({"Trainer","Module","Durantion/Mins","Who NEEDS training";unique(query(split(flatten(if(Sheet1!D5:D<>"",Sheet1!E5:E&char(9999)&Sheet1!D5:D&char(9999)&Sheet1!C5:C&char(9999)&if(Sheet1!F5:J="NEED",Sheet1!F2:J2,),)),char(9999)),"where Col1 is not null",0))})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed help!  I  can't wait to try your formula in the morning. I made an example sheet here: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBEgN0LI8lJpmO13rlmVnHhw8sHO9XaGcgBij6S34To/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Aresvik, I like it! Thanks! I was looking to see if there was a way to list it all in once cell but this will work perfectly, because I can make a pivot table from that sheet. Is the formula you used, the one you listed up there? I'll try to see if I can get it to work! <3